# Can my FireBase database layout cause issues if I use this approach?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have a FireBase structure that looks like this. I want to represent all countries in the world.

In this sample code there is only 9 countries and only United States and Venezuela have data to demonstrate my problem.

I have denormalization and flattens the data as much as I can.

What happens her is that user can search for street addresses like

```
US/California/Orange County/Orange/3138 E Maple Ave
```

In the db below it looks like this:

```
US/ADMINISTRATIVE_AREA_LEVEL_1/    
US/ADMINISTRATIVE_AREA_LEVEL_2    
US/LOCALITY    
US/STREET_ADDRESS    

  ....
  ....
  "AE": {
    "name": "United Arab Emirates"
  },
  "GB": {
    "name": "United Kingdom"
  },
  "US": {
    "name": "United States"
    "ADMINISTRATIVE_AREA_LEVEL_1": {
      "hjg86tghg8hubyhiuhb88ihi": {
        "level1": "California"
      },

    },
    "ADMINISTRATIVE_AREA_LEVEL_2": {
      "hjg86tghg8hubyhiuhb88ihi": {
        "level2": "Orange County"
      },
    },
    "LOCALITY": {
      "hjg86tghg8hubyhiuhb88ihi": {
        "level2": "Orange"
      },
    },
    "STREET_ADDRESS": {
      "hjg86tghg8hubyhiuhb88ihi": {
        "3138 E Maple Ave": {
        }
      }
    },
    "USER_LIST": {
      "hjg86tghg8hubyhiuhb88ihi": {
        "name": "Jhon Doe",
      }
    },
    "CHAT_LIST": {
      "hjg86tghg8hubyhiuhb88ihi": {
        "title": "Wam-Bam-CHAT",
      }
    },
    "chat_members": {
      "hjg86tghg8hubyhiuhb88ihi": {
      }
    },
    "chat_messages": {
      "hjg86tghg8hubyhiuhb88ihi": {
    },
  },
  "UM": {
    "name": "United States Minor Outlying Islands"
  },
  "UY": {
    "name": "Uruguay"
  },
  "UZ": {
    "name": "Uzbekistan"
  },
  "VU": {
    "name": "Vanuate"
  },
  "VE": {
    "name": "Venezuela"
       "ADMINISTRATIVE_AREA_LEVEL_1": {
      "swdkewsjdr34378943489324": {
        "level1": "California"
      },

    },
    "ADMINISTRATIVE_AREA_LEVEL_2": {
      "swdkewsjdr34378943489324": {
        "level2": "Orange County"
      },
    },
    "LOCALITY": {
      "swdkewsjdr34378943489324": {
        "level2": "Orange"
      },
    },
    "STREET_ADDRESS": {
      "swdkewsjdr34378943489324": {
        "3138 E Maple Ave": {
        }
      }
    },
    "USER_LIST": {
      "swdkewsjdr34378943489324": {
        "name": "Jhon Doe",
      }
    },
    "CHAT_LIST": {
      "swdkewsjdr34378943489324": {
        "title": "Wam-Bam-CHAT",
      }
    },
    "chat_members": {
      "swdkewsjdr34378943489324": {
      }
    },
    "chat_messages": {
      "swdkewsjdr34378943489324": {
    },
  },
  "VN": {
    "name": "Viet Nam"
    ....
    ....
```

When I create the Realtime Database Rules likes this: I have to create 240 root nods because of 240 countries right.
There´s a loot of `".read": "$uid === auth.uid"` and a loot of duplicate json since all `ADMINISTRATIVE_AREA_LEVEL_1` and others looks the same.
If i put the `ADMINISTRATIVE_AREA_LEVEL_1` as a root i will maybe have miljons of entries and for the STREET_ADDRESS there is 154 million alone for United States not to speak of the "world". So I group them like this, having the Country as key root node.

Small sample:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "SE": {
      "ADMINISTRATIVE_AREA_LEVEL_1": {
        "$uid": {
          ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
          ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
        }
      }
    },
    "VE": {
      "ADMINISTRATIVE_AREA_LEVEL_1": {
        "$uid": {
          ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
          ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My question is how can I furthermore make this more efficient and what bottleneck(s) can I look forward to. Is there a way to have this structure and centrally set a rule without explicitly writing it at all location

**UPDATE**
Probably i get this wrong but anyway here goes, after @FrankvanPuffelen answer I try this: Must test run this but does this work on all 240 countries in my above code..

```
{
  "rules": {
    "$country": {
      "ADMINISTRATIVE_AREA_LEVEL_1": {
        "$uid": {
          ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
          ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
        }
      },
      "ADMINISTRATIVE_AREA_LEVEL_2": {
        "$uid": {
          ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
          ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
        }
      },
      "LOCALITY": {
        "$uid": {
          ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
          ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
        }
      },
....and more
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**
Yes it works with a little tweek

```
{
  "rules": {
    "$hubaBuba": {
      "ADMINISTRATIVE_AREA_LEVEL_1": {
         ".read": "auth != null",
         ".write": "auth != null",
      },
      "ADMINISTRATIVE_AREA_LEVEL_2": {
           ".read": "auth != null",
           ".write": "auth != null",
      },
      "LOCALITY": {
        "$uid": {
          ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
          ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
        }
      },
....and more
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the rules for each country are the same, you can use a wildcard for the country:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "$country": {
      "ADMINISTRATIVE_AREA_LEVEL_1": {
        "$uid": {
          ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
          ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I understand that $uid is the current user but does this mean that the current user who have a path:  `$country/ADMINISTRATIVE_AREA_LEVEL_1/` can be `US/ADMI..` or `SE/ADMI..` or any country... and the Databas know , how? ....Takes some getting use to this abstraction thinking :)